# Load JavaScript file inside another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I'm using `node.js` and `socket.io` and doing a server/client thing. On my Server, is since its' not on a webpage, is there a way I can load the latest file (or latest jQuery?) so I can use jQuery functions inside my Server js file.

I tried doing `npm install jquery` then drag the `jquery` folder into my `node_modules` folder onto my website. Then at he top of my file I put `var $ = require('jQuery');` and then I run it and I get the error `Cannot find module 'location'`

Thanks

Comment: have you tried [node-jquery](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery) plugin?

Comment: Sounds like somewhere you're referencing a "location" module. That has nothing to do with jQuery. Find where the error is at and determine whether you actually need "location" or whether you're not including it properly.

Comment: Yes @Raminson, that is what I am doing now.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Funny because if I take out the `var $ = require('jQuery')` it goes away.. Here's my error: http://i.imgur.com/vVCOO.png

Comment: Why do you need jQuery in node.js?

Comment: So I can do specific functions only available in jQuery?

Comment: Can you put up some code on which you are doing `require('jQuery')`?

Comment: Well, I just have `var $ = require('jquery');` by itself and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this same issue. I created a small test applications (with express),  installed jquery afresh and things started working.

Checking my initial project a couple of changes seemed significant

1. I did an npm unisntall for jquery and jsdom
2. I did an npm install jquery (note, lowercase)
3. I changed my require('jQuery') to be require('jquery') (again, lowercase)

I think the significant part was removing and reinstalling jsdom and jquery but the others then were required to get things working again.